# Autoscaling solr - Add pull replicas, not NRT replicas

Tags: solr, solrj, autoscaling, solrcloud

I have a specific requirement where I just want to create only pull replicas using the solr autoscaling feature whenever the cluster starts the recovey process after a node failure.
However Using solrcloud autoscaling creates NRT type replicas when node goes down and brought up.
I have gone through the examples given in the policy specifcation list : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-autoscaling-policy-preferences.html#policy-specification but I am not able to find a example that limits replica creation by type.
I have also tried to set the cluster to limit the number of NRT replicas but in that case when autoscaling is done(a node made down), no new replicas get added as the max number of NRT replicas are already there.

So is it possible to acheive such functionality directly, if no, then please suggest an ideal approach for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replica type hint property was introduced in version 8.3 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13674

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_4_1/changes/Changes.html#v8.3.0.bug_fixes