# Solr 7.5 Auto scaling replica types

Tags: search, solr, autoscaling

I am using Solr version 7.5. I am trying to configure autoscaling in Solr, mainly by adding replicas. What is happening is, whenever Solr adds new replicas during autoscaling it only adds replicas of type NRT. What I need to achieve is Solr should only add replicas of type TLOG during every autoscaling event. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to upgrade to at least [Solr 8.3 to get support for replica type](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13674) when autoscaling. This is the same as in "[Autoscaling solr - Add pull replicas, not NRT replicas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428945/autoscaling-solr-add-pull-replicas-not-nrt-replicas)" - the type wasn't configurable before 8.3.

I suggest upgrading to the newest version if you're going to do the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mats. It looks like the replica type support is only added to the trigger "NodeAddedTrigger". I wonder if it supports the other autoscaling events too like the searchrate,metrc triggers..etc. Again any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd ask that on the `solr-user` mail list so you get more eyes on it - it's a rather narrow feature set.